# Can the at command in rest be simplified?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
rest(){
    echo "have a rest in "$1 " minutes"
    at -f /home/rest.sh now+$1 minutes
}
```

To edit a rest.sh script.

```
vim /home/rest.sh
xscreensaver-command --lock
```

To test it.

```
rest 60
have a rest in 60  minutes
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 7 at Thu Feb  9 11:15:00 2017
```

Can the `at` command in rest be simplifed?
To delete the /home/rest.sh, to pass parameter with pipe or other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at and batch read commands from standard input or a specified file which are to be executed at a later time, using /bin/sh.

`man at`

So, you can feed it commands with a [HEREDOC](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), like this:

```bash
rest(){
    echo "have a rest in "$1 " minutes"
    at now+$1 minutes <<EOF
    xscreensaver-command --lock
EOF
}
```

(note that the limit string `EOF` can not have any whitespace in front of it)